# how to add apostrophe to jQuery Validate regex?

Tags: jquery, regex, jquery-validate

I've tried escaping and putting an apostrophe in different places in this regex but I'm still getting the error. Where do I need to put it?

```
$.validator.addMethod("customvalidation",
       function(value, element) {
            return (/^[A-Za-z\d=#$%@_\-]+$/.test(value));
       },
"Sorry, no special characters allowed" 
);
```

Things I've tried:

```
 //putting the apostraphe before the @ sign without escaping
      (/^[A-Za-z\d=#$%'@_\-]+$/.test(value));

//putting the apostraphe as the last value in the brackets with and without escaping
      (/^[A-Za-z\d=#$%'@_\- \']+$/.test(value));
```

Comment: There's nothing special about apostrophe in regular expressions. You should be able to just add it into the brackets.

Comment: no matter where I put it I will get the error saying no special characters allowed

Comment: Make sure you're entering a real apostrophe, not a "smart quote".

Comment: Update your question to show what you tried. How can we tell what youre doing wrong if you don't show us>

Comment: ok I updated the post with some examples of what I've tried

Comment: The first one works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/hQf74/

Comment: @Spilot: Can you reproduce this error in any any of the online regex testers? I suspect you may not be getting `apostraphe` character in your input but something similar.

Comment: I'm using this on a form. When I submit the form with something like: Sade's Post, I get the error.

Comment: Try escaping `#` and `$`, the first one you can escape simply by using backslash `\#`, but to escape `$` I believe you need to use `$$`

Comment: @Spilot: Can you do `console.log(value);` before this method and see what it prints in your logs first.

Comment: console.log(value) gives me the value of whatever is in the input such as: Sade's Post. @Tafari, am I escaping both? where do I put the apostraphe if I escape #

Comment: I'm not sure where you guys are located, but I'm in NYC. It's almost 4am here and I'm exhausted. I will check back in late tomorrow and keep working on this, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have looked at your question multiple times and have gone through all of your comments. This comment strikes out:

> `console.log(value) gives me the value of whatever is in the input such as:`**Sade's Post**

You're right this will **not succeed**:

```
/^[A-Za-z\d=#$%'@_-]+$/.test("Sade's Post");
```

Problem is not `apostrophe` but it is existence of whitespace in your input string which is **not included in your character class**

Change your character class to include whitespace also:

```
[A-Za-z\d\s=#$%'@_-]
```

Now try this `regex.test`:

```
result = /^[A-Za-z\d\s=#$%'@_-]+$/.test("Sade's Post");
// returns true now
```